# OpenCV Compilation Error

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, pkg-config

I recently installed OpenCV on my laptop. After the installation of OpenCV 2.4.2 I tried to run and compile a basic program to Load and display and image. The code is given below.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
if( argc != 2)
{
 cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
 return -1;
}

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   

if(! image.data )                              
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "Display window", image );                   

waitKey(0);                                          
return 0;
}
```

This program is given on their website. Then for compiling command I used the command:

```
g++ `pkg-config opencv --cflags` p1.cpp  -o p1 `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

The compilation failed and the result was:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable


No package 'opencv' found


Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.


Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable


No package 'opencv' found


p1.cpp:1:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is not installation error, is it?

Comment: How did you build and install OpenCV?

Comment: @Astor I used this guide:  http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/

Comment: Are you sure that you done step 11? If yes, try to reboot system.

Comment: Did it. Still not working.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](http://www.samontab.com/web/2012/06/installing-opencv-2-4-1-ubuntu-12-04-lts/). I used it and your code builds OK.